# how to get the micro date from the system in php?

Tags: php

**Is it possible to get the milliseconds from the system with PHP?**

*For example:*
`"2015-10-28 13:02:45"` to get this data from the system till I know is possible to use `getdate()` or `time()`, but this functions don't give me the milliseconds. 
How then, I could get from the system something like this: `"2015-10-28 13:02:45.045"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a function to check the microtime

```
function udate($format, $utimestamp = null) {
      if (is_null($utimestamp))
        $utimestamp = microtime(true);

      $timestamp = floor($utimestamp);
      $milliseconds = round(($utimestamp - $timestamp) * 1000000);

      return date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $milliseconds, $format), $timestamp);
    }

    echo udate('Y-m-d H:i:s:u'); // 2010-11-15 21:21:00:987
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%06d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000000);
$d = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro, $t) );

print $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u"); 

?>
```